# How can I find the source of all images located in multiple classes with the same name?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to retrieve the source of all images located in the class *cheese*. There are only 4 classes named cheese that will ever exist in the document. Each one of those classes contains only 1 image of cheese inside of it.

I'm just started learning JavaScript yesterday because I need to use it for a C# project I'm working on that uses CefSharp. So, I'm sorry if some of my terms are inaccurate.

The following code will retrieve the source of the first 4 images in the document. Those 4 images are all the wanted images of cheese. However, if the pictures of flowers were ABOVE the pictures of cheese in the document, then it would instead retrieve 3 images of flowers, and 1 image of cheese. Which I don't want, because it's too inaccurate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/Pacific_Rock.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/oak_smoked.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/labne.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/exho.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/146500lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/90926mrdv3ch8z.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/91317lz.jpg"></div>

    <script>
        <!-- Stores a collection of all <img> elements in the document in a variable called pictures -->
        var pictures = document.images;

        <!-- Stores the first <img> element in the document in a variable called firstPicture -->
        var firstPicture = pictures[0].src;

        var secondPicture = pictures[1].src;
        var thirdPicture = pictures[2].src;
        var fourthPicture = pictures[3].src;

        <!-- Displays an alert box showing the first, second, third, and fourth <img> element in the document -->
        alert(firstPicture + "\n" + secondPicture + "\n" + thirdPicture + "\n" + fourthPicture)
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The following code will retrieve the source of the 4 images of cheese more accurately by targeting all of the images inside of the *content* class. The following code will still accomplish the main goal even if the images of flowers are above the images of cheese in the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/Pacific_Rock.jpg"></div>
        <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/oak_smoked.jpg"></div>
        <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/labne.jpg"></div>
        <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/exho.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/146500lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/90926mrdv3ch8z.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/91317lz.jpg"></div>

    <script>
        var pictures = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
        var firstPicture = pictures.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
        var secondPicture = pictures.getElementsByTagName('img')[1].src;
        var thirdPicture = pictures.getElementsByTagName('img')[2].src;
        var fourthPicture = pictures.getElementsByTagName('img')[3].src;
        alert(firstPicture + "\n" + secondPicture + "\n" + thirdPicture + "\n" + fourthPicture)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The 2 blocks of code above are just examples. The **real** document's code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/146500lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/90926mrdv3ch8z.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/91317lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/Pacific_Rock.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/oak_smoked.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/labne.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/exho.jpg"></div>
    <script>
        var pictures = document.images;
        var firstPicture = pictures[0].src;
        var secondPicture = pictures[1].src;
        var thirdPicture = pictures[2].src;
        var fourthPicture = pictures[3].src;
        alert(firstPicture + "\n" + secondPicture + "\n" + thirdPicture + "\n" + fourthPicture)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I accurately target the 4 *cheese* classes and return the source of all images inside of the classes? There will only ever be 1 image of cheese in each class and I want to store the value of each image into a variable and display them in an alert box. I'm NOT wanting you guys to just hand over code to me and that's that. I would like an explanation of how everything works.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question! :)

**This question has been answered, thanks to jfriend00.**

I am using the following code to accomplish the desired result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/146500lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/90926mrdv3ch8z.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/91317lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/Pacific_Rock.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/oak_smoked.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/labne.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/exho.jpg"></div>

    <script>
        var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img");
        var img1 = imgs[0].src;
        var img2 = imgs[1].src;
        var img3 = imgs[2].src;
        var img4 = imgs[3].src;
        alert(img1 + "\n" + img2 + "\n" + img3 + "\n" + img4)
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector query to get just the targeted images:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    console.log(imgs[i].src);
}
```

This will find any `<img>` tag that is a child of an object with `class="cheese"` and then loop through the collection of imgs it found.  `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is an array-like object (it doesn't have actual Array methods on it, but it does have `.length` and can index with `[i]`).

You can read more about `document.querySelectorAll()` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).  It takes a [CSS selector string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) as the input and will return a nodeList of all matching DOM elements.

If you wanted the `.src` URLs in an array, you could do this:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img");
var srcArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    srcArray.push(imgs[i].src);
}
// srcArray holds the URLs here
```

Or, a little more advanced:

```
var srcArray = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img"), function(img) {
    return img.src;
});
```

---

**Here's a working snippet:**

```js
var srcArray = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img"), function(img) {
    return img.src;
});

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = srcArray.join("<br>");
```

```css
#results {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div> 
<div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/146500lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/90926mrdv3ch8z.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flowers"><img src="http://cdn1.1800flowers.com/wcsstore/Flowers/images/catalog/91317lz.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/Pacific_Rock.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/oak_smoked.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/labne.jpg"></div>
    <div class="cheese"><img src="http://www.cheese.com/media/img/cheese/exho.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to get an array of the `src`s: `var srcs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img"), function(img) { return img.src; });` or on ES2015 (or with a shim) `var srcs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cheese img")).map(function(img) { return img.src; });`

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you will be able to do something like this

```
var imagePath = ""
jQuery(".cheese").each(function (index) {
  imagePat += jQuery(this).children("img").attr("src") + "\n";
})
```

Comment: Usually, jQuery answers should be offered ONLY to questions that specifically reference jQuery or have tagged the question for jQuery.